# vba macro excel - formula question after running a macro

Tags: excel, vba

i have a simple question but i can't find an answer in google.

i have the following simple code:

```
cells(1,1)= cells(1,2) + cells(1,3)
```

i want to be able to show the user the result in cells(1,1) but that he can also see how i got it (if he stands on the cell he should see that i did =B1+C1).
how can i do it?

moreover, i want him to be able to change the numbers in B1,C1 and get a new result in A1 like regular he could do in regular excel function
how can i do it?

thanks!

Comment: A formula would do exactly what you want so why not use one?  If you *really* want to do this with VBA then you can look at the worksheet_change event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to just add a formula to the cell and not put in a value.

Check this out.
[VBA To Add Formula To Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987975/vba-to-add-formula-to-cell)

Not exactly what you are asking but it shows you how to add a formula in your vba code.